# How to understand xargs

Tags: xargs

Saying that I have two files `t1` and `t2`, they have the same content: `abc`.

Now I want to delete all files, who contains the string `abc`.

So I tried to execute the command: `grep -rl abc . | rm` but it doesn't work.

Then I add `xargs`: `grep -rl abc . | xargs rm` and it works.

I can't understand clearly what `xargs` did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` puts the output as `stdout`. But `rm` cannot process data from `stdin` (the pipe links both).

You want instead, that the output of `grep` is put as argument of `rm`. So `xargs` command "convert" stdin into arguments of xargs first argument, and it call the command (the first argument).

As alternative, you could do

```
rm `grep -rl abc .`
```

or

```
rm $(grep -rl abc .)
```

But `xargs` handles well also the case where there are too many arguments for a single call of the command. The above command will give you shell error (argument string too long).

Answer (score 0):

`rm` doesn't read from standard input (except when prompting, like with `-i`) but takes its arguments on the command line. That's what `xargs` does for you: read things from standard input and give them to `rm` as arguments.

Example with `echo`:

```
$ (echo a; echo b; date) | xargs echo
a b tor 12 apr 2018 14:18:50 CEST
```